# Why does this [circular] element is appended at the end of the array?

Tags: javascript

when running this code:

```js
function arrayToList(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return {
      value: arr[0],
      rest: null
    };
  } else {
    return {
      value: arr[0],
      rest: arrayToList(arr.splice(1))
    };
  }
}

function listToArray(list, arr = []) {
  if (list.rest == null) {
    return list.value;
  } else {

    arr.push(list.value);
    arr.push(listToArray(list.rest, arr))
    return arr;

  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])));
```

which is supposed to convert an array to a linked-list then back to an array, i get these weird `[Circular]` symbols appearing - what are these?

output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [Circular], [Circular], [Circular] ]
```

Comment: This is used to represent an element of the array which is the array itself. You couldn't represent this element fully, as it would expand recursively and infinitely in place.

Comment: what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: The problem is that the last call to `listToArray(list.rest, arr)` will return `arr` which means that this call `arr.push(listToArray(list.rest, arr))` adds `arr` to `arr`

Comment: @Nina Schotz The code is an exercise from eloquent javascript. I should make a list from an array, as an example the arrayToList function works perfectly. Then make a listToArray function, that part I'm stuck in. But I think Titus and Gershy are right, I'm adding arr as an element to arr at every recursice call except the first and last call, that's why i only get [circular] when length of arr is bigger than two.

Comment: @HiCham btw, I believe the way you're using the term "list" will confuse people - I think you're looking for the term "linked-list" instead! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Circular]` symbol is used to represent an element of the array which is the array itself. One could never represent this element fully, as it would expand recursively and infinitely in place.

The simplest way to see this is:

```js
let a = [];
a.push(a);
console.log(a);
```

Note that stackoverflow's snippet system has a different way of visualizing arrays which contain themselves. If you run this code in your own environment you'll see the `[Circular]` phenomenon occur.

Comment: Question answered correctly!! For future reference, here's the corrected function.

`function listToArray (list, arr=[])
{
 if (list.rest === null)
 {
  arr.push (list.value);
  console.log (arr);

 }else {
  arr.push (list.value);
  listToArray (list.rest, arr)
 }
 return arr;
}`